# Content moderation and changing node state on default or latest revision

Tags: 8

I am using content moderation and sometimes I update the moderation state of my entity programmatically in a hook node presave for example. I usually  have the entity and I can do
`$node->set('moderation_state', "needs review");` , however my question is, if for some reason in a controller, I want to do the same thing in a function that doesn't have the node entity as parameter, I wanna load the node by ID then change its state.
should I use `Node::Load($nid);` which gives me the node default/current version before doing `$node->set('moderation_state', "needs review");` or should I have to load the latest revision then set the moderation state on the latest revision instead of setting it on the current/default revision ?

Comment: Both are possible, but the second option probably makes more sense. For how to load the node, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/303872/how-do-i-programmatically-publish-the-latest-revision, only that you set a different moderation state.

Comment: thanks @4uk4 yes loading the last revision makes more sense